# How to I specify image size of google slide API PNG export?

Tags: python, google-slides-api

I was able to successfully run the below code to generate a URL with an image of my google slide but when I try specifying the thumbnailProperties, it says: "Got an unexpected keyword argument "thumbnailProperties"". I followed this documentation: https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/getThumbnail?hl=es

Any ideas on what I need to change?

```
service = build('slides', 'v1', credentials=creds)

img = service.presentations().pages().getThumbnail(
        presentationId=PRESENTATION_ID, 
        pageObjectId='gd7f6eed13a_1_17',
        # thumbnailProperties = {'thumbnailSize': 'LARGE'}
        ).execute()
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, please modify as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
service = build('slides', 'v1', credentials=creds)

img = service.presentations().pages().getThumbnail(
        presentationId=PRESENTATION_ID, 
        pageObjectId='gd7f6eed13a_1_17',
        thumbnailProperties_thumbnailSize='LARGE' # Modified
        ).execute()
```

By this, the following result is obtained. When you want to retrieve the thumbnail image, please download it from the following `contentUrl`. In this case, the access token is not required to be used.

```
{
  'height': 900,
  'width': 1600,
  'contentUrl': 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/###=s1600'
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Method: presentations.pages.getThumbnail](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/getThumbnail)